# Describing the degree/level/amount when using the -さ adjective ending

Tags: grammar, adjectives

When using words like 速さ or 美味しさ to refer to the degree of some quality, can we be more specific about the degree?

For example, can we say "美味しさが高い" or "美味しさが低い"? Maybe "大きい・小さい" (or some other pair) is more appropriate than "高い・低い"?

Can we directly compare the "美味しさ" of two different things, or should we just use something like "XのほうがYより美味しい"?

Answer (score 1):

It's not absolutely impossible to combine 大きい or 高い with おいしさ or 速さ but you usually use ある / ない / 半端{はんぱ}ではない. You can use it for comparative degree too like こっちのほうが美味しさがある. On the other hand, うまみ or 甘{あま}み get along with 強い / 弱い for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

- 親しさが高い異性の名前の呼び方の順位ってどんなかんじでしょうか？
- 宝石としての美しさが高いアイテムだと思います。
- ........ というのは他アプリでもよく見られる怪しさが高い内容となっています。
- そして、「社会的望ましさ」が高いアナウンサーは、ニュース報道番組のキャスターをしているようなアナウンサーでした。

So, i suppose it's more common than i thought.

But the following expressions are more traditional and common (I think).

- 完成度が増した。　満足度が減った。　　利用頻度が減った。　さらに注目度が増したモデル。　　勘違い度が増した夫について弁護士に相談してみた ...
- パロディー性が高まっている。　　... ユーモア性の豊かな表現でなくては、人の心を開かない。
- 赤みが増している。　　頬の赤みが増した。　　うまみが増している。　　「あまり うまみ のない商売」

Comment: `頼の赤み` -> なんて読むんですか。「[頬]{ほほ}の赤み」ですか。

Comment: ん。。？　一番下の行の　×「 **頼**の赤み」 ⇒ ○「 **頬** (ほほ)の赤み」　←ここの漢字が間違えてますよ、っていう意味だったんですが。。よく見たら、「利用**頻**度(ひんど)」が「利用**頬**度」になってるじゃないですか・・。　ついでだから両方直しときましたよ・・